# Difference between \tableofcontents and \tableofcontents{}

Tags: table-of-contents

What if any difference is there between `\tableofcontents` and `\tableofcontents{}`?

I noticed that inserting a TOC in LyX uses the `{}` while the `classicthesis` template for LyX does not. Any reason?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no difference at all in any of the usual classes `\tableofcontents` doesn't take an argument so the `{}` just open and closes a group but otherwise does nothing.

Automated TeX generators tend to put `{}` after command names to avoid problems with following text.

`\tableofcontentshello` wouldn't work whereas `\tableofcontents{}hello` is OK. In this case though that isn't likely to be an issue as `\tableofcontents` is usually followed by a sectioning command or a blank line rather than text.

Comment: Thanks, that perfectly answer's my question and the reasoning makes a lot of sense.